# In sqlite-jdbc driver(3.23 or 3.30),fail update when string is too long, without any exception. But in command line and navicat, it's OK

Tags: string, sqlite, jdbc, long-integer

**SQL**

```
replace into articles(id,grade,no,title,content,newchars,update_time)
values(1394823098212,'1','8','title','**LongUtf8String**',1614001996557)
```

If the length of **LongUtf8String** exceeds 2689 bytes, the operation will fail, without any exception.
In sqlite command line and navicat, it can work.

**Table definition:**
create table if not exists articles (
id long not null primary key,
grade tinyint not null,
no smallint not null,
title varchar(255) not null,
content text not null,
newchars text not null
);

I can't find any configuration items in SQLiteConfig.

**Are there any ways to overcome the limit?
Thanks!!!**

Answer (score 0):

It is my fault:(((
I limited the length when check parameters, and discard it without prompt.